# How can i get attribute value from a checkbox if it's checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

Well, I have this text input that gets sum of all the attributes of "price" inside all checkboxes are checked.
now i can't get an attribute value from a checkbox.

here is my function:

```
function sum_options() {
    var options = [];
    $("#form-field-1-11-1").attr("price", 500);
    $("#form-field-1-11-2").attr("price", 500);
    $("#form-field-1-11-3").attr("price", 0);
    $("#form-field-1-11-4").attr("price", 300);
    $("#form-field-1-11-5").attr("price", 500);
    $("#form-field-1-11-6").attr("price", 500);
    $("#form-field-1-11-7").attr("price", 1250);
    $("#form-field-1-11-8").attr("price", 500);
    $("#form-field-1-11-9").attr("price", 700);
    options[0] = $("#form-field-1-11-1");
    options[1] = $("#form-field-1-11-2");
    options[2] = $("#form-field-1-11-3");
    options[3] = $("#form-field-1-11-4");
    options[4] = $("#form-field-1-11-5");
    options[5] = $("#form-field-1-11-6");
    options[6] = $("#form-field-1-11-7");
    options[7] = $("#form-field-1-11-8");
    options[8] = $("#form-field-1-11-9");
    var total = 0;
    $.each(options, function() {
        this.on("change", function() {
            total += this.attr("price");
        });
    });
    $("#sum-field").val(total);
}
```

thanks!!!

Comment: Note that within `each()` `this` is a DOMElement which does not have `on()` and `attr()` methods; you need to convert it to a jQuery object before calling those methods using `$(this)`. See my answer below for a more complete answer which also improves the logic you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of the Value attribute you can do something like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

Or if you have set a class or id for it, you can:

```
$('#check_id').val();
$('.check_class').val();
```

However this will return the same value whether it is checked or not, this can be confusing as it is differnt to the submitted form behaviour.

To check whether it is checked or not, do:

```
if ($('#check_id').is(":checked"))
{
  // it is checked
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is a *lot* more complex than it needs to be.

Firstly, you should use `data-*` attributes to assign custom data to an element. Creating your own non-standard attributes will mean your HTML is invalid and can lead to other issues. Also, if your code is relying on the `price` attribute, then it should be in the DOM when the page loads.

Secondly there's no need to build an array of single elements. You can select them all in to a single jQuery object and set a `change()` event handler on them in a single call. I grouped them by `class` in the below example.

Lastly you can get the total of all the prices by looping through the `:checked` boxes and adding up their prices. Try this:

```js
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
  });
  $("#sum-field").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="form-field-1-11-1" class="checkbox" data-price="500" />
<input type="checkbox" id="form-field-1-11-2" class="checkbox" data-price="500" />
<input type="checkbox" id="form-field-1-11-3" class="checkbox" data-price="0" />
<input type="checkbox" id="form-field-1-11-4" class="checkbox" data-price="300" />
<!-- other checkboxes here... -->

<input type="text" id="sum-field" />
```

Comment: @Menachem any specific reason you decided to change the accepted answer after all this time?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to parse the return value to a number:

```
parseInt(this.attr("price"));
```

the attr() function is returning a string value.